# Calling node delete (node_delete_multiple) is not deleting all comments from database

Tags: comments, nodes

When I do a query on the database (`SELECT * FROM comment c  where c.nid = 119445765;`)  I get a `12 rows in set (0.00 sec)`
The I call `node_delete_multiple(array(119445765))`. 
Then I go back to the database and perform the same query `SELECT * FROM comment c  where c.nid = 119445765;`)  I get a `5 rows in set (0.00 sec)`.

Now These may be replies to comments since this is a forum. However, how do I ensure they are deleted? Do I have to perform the query myself?

UPDATE:

I have stepped debug this issue here is my notes:
1. `node_delete_mutliple` -> invokes `comment_node_delete`
2. `comment_node_delete` perform this query `$cids = db_query('SELECT cid FROM {comment} WHERE nid = :nid', array(':nid' => $node->nid))->fetchCol();` and it correctly returns  all cids  associated with the node.
3. `comment_node_delete` calls `comment_delete_multiple` which in turns calls `$comments = comment_load_multiple($cids);` **NOW** `comment_load_multiple($cids);` is not returning the correct number of comments. Surprisingly it is always ommiting comments by a certain user.

I am continuing to debug and will add more info,

**Update 2**

```
 $cids = db_query('SELECT cid FROM {comment}
 WHERE nid = :nid', array(':nid'  => 119318471))->fetchCol();
 dpm($cids); // Gives the correct number of $cids
 $comments = entity_load('comment', $cids, $conditions = array(), TRUE);
 dpm($comments); // Is an array with fewer comments than number of $cids
```

So the problem so far is in entity_load.

**Note** I failed to mention that the database is migrated from another system and may contain some bad references.

Comment: Have you tried flushing cache and running cron just to make sure there's no intentional delay happening?

Comment: Yes. I just posted an update. I think I am onto something .

Comment: Do you have an exception, like would throm comment_delete_multiple in comment module, line 1624 ?

Comment: no exception is thrown, because entity_load is not returning the correct correct number of comments object.

Answer (score 1):

you should check the watchdog table to see if there are any errors. The function calls comment_delete_multiple and with in that functions deletes all the replies as well.

If there was any error during this process it would rollback to a specific point in this case I guess it would be during the delete process of child comments. Tne information would be stored in the watchdog table with type set to comment. This would give you a hint as to why it was not deleted.

Comment: I looked at it, no errors. Because it is doing the correct thing on a fewer nodes that it is supposed to.  entity_load('comment', $cids, $conditions = array(), TRUE); is not returning the correct number of comments objects.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it is because of some incorrect migration of data. In other words, the problem lies with bad references in my database and not a drupal bug.
 I traced down the problem to `CommentController`. In there there the method for building a query add additional joins:

```
protected function buildQuery($ids, $conditions = array(), $revision_id = FALSE) {
$query = parent::buildQuery($ids, $conditions, $revision_id);
// Specify additional fields from the user and node tables.
$query->innerJoin('node', 'n', 'base.nid = n.nid');
$query->addField('n', 'type', 'node_type');
$query->innerJoin('users', 'u', 'base.uid = u.uid');
$query->addField('u', 'name', 'registered_name');
$query->fields('u', array('uid', 'signature', 'signature_format', 'picture'));
return $query;
```

}

When commenting out the inner joins the comments were returned in from the entity_load function. However, **since** the data was not migrated well, the uid associated with the comment does not exist. And hence the inner join with the user table was empty for that specific node. When I commentned it out I got this result (sample result):

```
... (Object) stdClass
cid (String, 9 characters ) 119410583
pid (String, 1 characters ) 0
nid (String, 9 characters ) 119318471
uid (String, 6 characters ) 983643
subject (String, 14 characters ) Re:
hostname (String, 0 characters ) 
created (String, 10 characters ) 1340215426
changed (String, 10 characters ) 1340215426
status (String, 1 characters ) 1
thread (String, 3 characters ) 02/
name (NULL)
mail (NULL)
homepage (NULL)
language (String, 3 characters ) und
new (Integer) 0
node_type (String, 13 characters ) comment_node_
```

Note name, mail.